# represent the following in a power series

Tags: summation, power-series, taylor-expansion

> Represent $1/(1-x)^2$ in a power series using the fact that $$\ln (x+1)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{x^n}{n}$$

First i derived $\ln(x+1)$ and its sum which equaled:
$$1/(x+1)= \sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} x^{n-1}$$
then I substituted $-x$ for $x$ giving me
$$1/(1-x)= \sum_{n=1} x^n$$
then I derived this one more time to get the answer so I got
$$1/(1-x)^2 = \sum_{n=2} nx^{n-1}$$
which is the wrong answer... The right answer is exactly the same but it starts from $1$. How?????? When we derive we add $+1$, so how it is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a misunderstanding in connection with the derivation of a series
\begin{align*}
A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n
\end{align*}
We obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}A(x)&=\sum_{\color{blue}{n=0}}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}=\sum_{\color{blue}{n=1}}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}\\
\end{align*}

Here we can increment the index $n$ by one, since the summand with $n=0$ is zero: $0a_0=0$ and has no contribution. Note, we do *not add* one to the index due to differentiation. It is simply due to the cancellation of the first summand in this case.

> The derivation of the current series gives
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{d}{dx}\ln (x+1)&= \frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{\color{blue}{n=1}}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{x^n}{n}\right)\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(-1)^{n-1} \frac{x^{n-1}}{n}\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-x)^{n-1}
> \end{align*}
>
> Since the index $n$ starts here with $n=1$, there is no summand with factor $n=0$ which can be cancelled.

Comment: soo when deriving a summation, we do not always just shift the index... we need to see what is inside the summation, correct?

Comment: sooo to be safe, if were not sure if the summand =0, we should just keep and index and not shift it, right??

Comment: @exchangehelpforuni: Correct.

Comment: if n=0 has no contribution but we keep it, will our answer be considered wrong, or is it okay to jsut keep it??

Comment: @exchangehelpforuni: Both variations are correct and quite ok. It is only a matter of convenience.

Answer (score 0):

You know that
$$
\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n}
$$
so
$$
\ln(1-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}
$$
Note the sum starts from $n=1$, not $2$.

Differentiating,
$$
-\frac{1}{1-x}=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n-1}
$$
that can be rewritten
$$
\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n
$$
By differentiating again you get
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^n
$$

---

Some explanations are apparently in order. Let's consider the general case
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n
$$
Then the derivative can be written
$$
f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}
$$
because the constant term $a_0$ disappears and it's better to avoid writing the term
$$
0a_0x^{0-1}
$$
which would be undefined at $0$.

In the case of
$$
\ln(1-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}
$$
we have
$$
\ln(1-x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n
$$
where
$$
a_n=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $n=0$}\\[4px]
-\dfrac{1}{n} & \text{if $n>0$}
\end{cases}
$$
so the derivative is
$$
-\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)x^{n-1}=
-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n
$$
the last equality by pulling the minus sign outside and changing indexing.

Comment: but when u diffrentiate, dont u add +1 to the index????

Comment: when u derive, u add +1!!!

Comment: @exchangehelpforuni Why should I? What's the derivative of $x+x^2$? Constant terms disappear, non constant ones don't.

Comment: no i mean when u derive a series summation, u add 1

Comment: for instance n=0, after u derive it will start at 1

Comment: @exchangehelpforuni What you say is simply not true. You're going to make many mistakes by blindly follow (wrong) “rules”.

Comment: "Note that the start of the summation changed from n=0 to n=1, since the constant term a0 has 0 as its derivative." index shifting when deriving,, isnt that true????

Comment: @exchangehelpforuni I added some explanations.

Comment: i did not understand one single word

Comment: @exchangehelpforuni I will try to explain in other manner your problem: you have $-\frac1{1-x}=\frac{d}{dx}(-x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}-\ldots)=-1-x-x^2-\ldots=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$